# Negation of a E quantifier in a Modal Logic T System?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

In System T its possible to conclude:

(1) □Ex->Ex

Therefore its possible to conclude:

(2) Ex->◊Ex

But whats the result, if I negate the existence quantifier? Is it:

(3) ~Ex->~◊Ex

or is it:

(4) ~Ex->◊~Ex

I found nothing in the usual introduction textbooks, but Im not a (modal) logic expert. Im thankful for all your answers

Comment: Not clear; you are trying to derive the negated formula from what ?

Comment: You have to negate formulas, and **not** quantifiers.

Comment: My question is: If nothing existists (~Ex), is it inpossible (~◊) that something existists (Ex)? That is what I was going for with (3). And can i show (3) in the T system?

Comment: Obviously, (4) follows from (2).

Comment: From (1), by contrapostion, we get: **~∃x → ~□∃x** i.e. **~∃x → ◊~∃x**.

Comment: Intuitively, if something does not exists, it can not exists in some world. Thus, its existence is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

As @MauroALLEGRANZA mentions, you do get

> (4) ~Ex->◊~Ex

I'd say it just follows from System T in general:

System T makes the accessibility relation reflexive, so that if there is no x with a certain property P in a world w, then there is a possible world relative to w, namely w itself, where there is no x with property P.